# Migrate files into dynamic paths

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a constant defined in my migration definition like so:

```
  constants:
    destination: "private://working_papers/"
```

There are 30,000 files that will come in as part of the migration. I would like to create directory destinations on the fly, based on source field values or whatever I want.

So:

`destination: constants/destination`

Would become:

`destination: constants/destination/@source_field_value/@source_field_value2`

This would be to reduce the raw number of files appearing in a given directory. When I try the above, nothing happens, even though the migration succeeds. The files don't go anywhere.

How can I do this? For reference, here is the field in the process section of the definition:

```
  field_paper_working_paper:
    plugin: file_import
    source: doc_format_url
    destination: constants/destination
    uid: 1
    rename: TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain a `concat` process plugin to your `destination` property so that it contains the result of concatenated source & constant values:

```
field_paper_working_paper: 
  plugin: file_import 
  source: doc_format_url 
  destination: 
    plugin: concat
    source:
      - constants/destination
      - '/'
      - source_field_value
      - '/'
      - source_field_value
  uid: 1
  rename: TRUE
```

Comment: I thought it would be this easy, and I tried this, but I get this error in the console: "[error]  TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::getValue() must be of the type array, null given" when I set it back, the error goes away.

Comment: Ah, I think it might either be related to the plugin not excepting string constants or @field values. I've seen this problem unfortunately it was about 6-9 months ago so my memory is fuzzy.

Comment: Wait, I am checking the FileImport plugin. I may have done it wrong.

Comment: I have the pseudo field setup in the migration, but its not adding the source field value on the end.

Comment: Now it works, removing '@' did it. I am honestly baffled by this one.

Comment: Yeah, I remember stumbling over psudofields in my last Drupal migration. Doc sources were scant and it wasn't very clear when/where I could use them. I updated the example code to match what worked for you.

Comment: I think they reference other destination fields defined in the migration itself. For example if you had a `field_foo` field defined in the YML, at the same level as `field_paper_working_paper`, you can get access to the result of that migrated value with `@field_foo`. Source columns/cells/whatever you want to call them don't need the same special syntax as they're already covered just using the name